# Does referencing the JDK namespaces from within a .NET application require the Java runtime to be installed?

Tags: vb.net, namespaces, j#

I'm in a VB.NET application. I have referenced some java.* namespaces in my file and am utilizing objects and methods from this namespace throughout the code. Presumably this is relying upon J# to compile.

```
Imports java.util
Imports java.util.zip
Imports java.io
```

Are these JDK namespaces fully contained in the .NET framework, or will my clients need to have Java installed when they go to run my application?

As a side note, I have not explicity referenced any external Java DLL's or anything. This is all pure .NET as far as my code is concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they're within the J# DLLs, which I strongly suspect VB is referencing for you automatically. If you open your binaries up in Reflector, I'm sure you'll see a reference to `vjslib.dll` there.

There's no dependency on an actual JRE/JDK being installed.

Personally I would try to migrate away from them, however. If you need more compression options than `System.IO.Compression` it's worth looking at [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/). Microsoft no longer ships J# as a product, and the idea of trying to port all the Java 1.1.4 classes to .NET, including their quirks, has always made me nervous.

`vjslib.dll` doesn't even ship by default with either the framework or Visual Studio these days...